# Javascript: instead of controlling with buttons control slider with scroll down or scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which will make a simple slider with buttons to navigate.

Now I need to make this slider controllable with scrolling.

When the user scrolls down, focus will be moved to the next slider, and also in reverse.

Buttons will be available too. So, there will be 2 options to control it. With buttons next and back and also with scrolling down or up.

Is there any option of how to do it in the easiest way?

```js
var lottieone = document.getElementById('lottieone');
var lottietwo = document.getElementById('lottietwo');
var lottiethree = document.getElementById('lottiethree');
var lottiefour = document.getElementById('lottiefour');

$('#lottieone').show();
$('#lottietwo').hide();
$('#lottiethree').hide();
$('#lottiefour').hide();


function missionsSlide() {
  $('#lottieone').hide();
  $('#lottietwo').show();
  $('#lottiethree').hide();
  $('#lottiefour').hide();
}

function missionsSlideBacc() {
  $('#lottieone').hide();
  $('#lottietwo').show();
  $('#lottiethree').hide();
  $('#lottiefour').hide();
}

function researchSlide() {
  $('#lottieone').hide();
  $('#lottietwo').hide();
  $('#lottiethree').show();
  $('#lottiefour').hide();
}

function educationSlide() {
  $('#lottieone').hide();
  $('#lottietwo').hide();
  $('#lottiethree').hide();
  $('#lottiefour').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slider">
  <div id="lottieone" class="lottieSlide">
    <div class="content">
      <button onclick="missionsSlide()">HOME</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lottietwo" class="lottieSlide mainSliders">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>MISSIONS</h1>
      <button onclick="researchSlide()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lottiethree" class="lottieSlide mainSliders">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>RESEARCH</h1>
      <button onclick="missionsSlideBacc()">Back</button>
      <button onclick="educationSlide()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lottiefour" class="lottieSlide mainSliders">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>EDUCATION</h1>
      <button onclick="researchSlide()">Back</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You forgot to paste the code you tried after researching on how to detect mousewheel events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use an `i` index.
- Create `prev()` and `next()` functions
- Use the `"wheel"` Event and its `deltaY`
- Use CSS `transition` and `transform` `translateX()` for a better UX effect
- Use a flag to prevent too many scrolls-animations - and use `"transitionend"` to reset the flag

```js
$(".slider").each(function() {

  let i = 0; // Start at slide index 0

  const $btns = $(".prev, .next", this);
  const $slides = $(".slides", this);
  const $slide = $(".slide", this);
  const tot = $slide.length;
  const mod = (n, max) => ((n % max) + max) % max;
  let canWheel = true;
  
  $slides.on("transitionend", () => canWheel = true);

  const anim = () => {
    $slides.css({transform: `translateX(${-100*i}%)`});
  };

  const prev = () => {
    i = mod(--i, tot);
    anim();
  };

  const next = () => {
    i = mod(++i, tot);
    anim();
  };

  $btns.on("click", (evt) => $(evt.currentTarget).is(".prev") ? prev() : next());
  $(this).on('wheel', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (!canWheel) return;
    canWheel = false;
    evt.originalEvent.deltaY < 0 ? prev() : next();
  });
  anim(); // INIT!

});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  transition: 1s;
}

.slide {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
      <h1>HOME</h1>
      <button type="button" class="next">Missions &rarr;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h1>MISSIONS</h1>
      <button type="button" class="prev">&larr;Home</button>
      <button type="button" class="next">Research &rarr;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h1>RESEARCH</h1>
      <button type="button" class="prev">&larr; Missions</button>
      <button type="button" class="next">Education &rarr;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h1>EDUCATION</h1>
      <button type="button" class="prev">&larr; Research</button>
      <button type="button" class="next">HOME</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, man! But I need to have first slide different. With different buttons and different layout. How can I do that?

Comment: And next problem when is it on fullscreen it will scroll on one scroll lot of times. I really need when user scroll down will go to only next one slide.

Comment: Niceee thank you so much. Last thing, sorry for that but can we use basic fadein and fadeout effect to do that? Not like sliding but basic fade effect. Thanks man so much

Comment: And sometimes when I scroll one time it will move me through 2 slides.